# Google Spreadsheet MATCH for multiple strings

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to find the formula to `MATCH()` for multiple strings. Normally I would just use the wildcard like `MATCH("String1*String2";A:A)` where `String1` and `String2` are two strings to be found in one cell of column A but these two could be separated with any other string but the wildcard does not work in this case.

A more complex version of the problem is when `String1` and `String2` could occur in any order inside one cell.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

try regex:

```
=REGEXMATCH(A1, "string1|string2")
```

Comment: Thank you but I'm not sure how REGEXTMATCH() would find a position (row) of a matched cell?

Comment: like this: `=ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(IF(REGEXMATCH(A:A, "string1|string2"), ROW(A:A), )))`

Comment: It works with some minor changes (`.*?` instead of `|` as it is for both strings matched together) but looks very complex and takes much processor-time. Would love to see something more simple.